# C# Selenium 4: Setup request interception

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium4

I'm trying to use Selenium 4 to log requests during manual usage of Chrome browser.

The issue is that request interception stops after around 40 seconds of usage (approximately).

I've tried to change commandTimeout but it didn't change anything.
Also I've tried to look into chromedriver logs but I didn't find anithing there.

Here's my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Enable chromedriver logging
        var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        service.LogPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "chromedriver.log";
        service.EnableVerboseLogging = true;
        var options = new ChromeOptions();

        var webDriver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
        var devToolsSession = webDriver.CreateDevToolsSession();
        devToolsSession.Network.Enable(new EnableCommandSettings());

        EventHandler<RequestInterceptedEventArgs> requestIntercepted = (sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Request.Url);
        };

        RequestPattern requestPattern = new RequestPattern();
        requestPattern.InterceptionStage = InterceptionStage.Request;
        requestPattern.ResourceType = ResourceType.Image;
        var setRequestInterceptionCommandSettings = new SetRequestInterceptionCommandSettings();
        setRequestInterceptionCommandSettings.Patterns = new RequestPattern[] { requestPattern };
        devToolsSession.Network.SetRequestInterception(setRequestInterceptionCommandSettings);
        devToolsSession.Network.RequestIntercepted += requestIntercepted;

        while (true)
        {
            webDriver.Url = "https://translate.google.com/";
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            webDriver.Navigate().Refresh();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ever solve this?  I'm not seeing what I would normally see in the Network tab within the chromedriver.log but maybe it's the same 40 second thing you are running into.

Comment: No luck from my side for now. I've created issue on Selenium github: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8960 Maybe they will tell us something

Comment: There is some working solutions on GitHub (link above) but I don't see them useful because of lack of api documentation and chome version dependency. For now I'm using python and https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/. It's really easy to reach my goal with it.

Answer (score 2):

As of Selenium 4 beta-1, you can use the `Fetch` API and retrieve the same resluts (SetRequestIntercepted is deprecated in ChromeTools as late as December 29, 2020).

In either case, the key point for both `RequestIntercepted` (prior to deprecation) and `Fetch` to be able to continue after intercepting the request is to capture the `RequestId`.

With `Fetch` this can be done in `ContinueRequest()`:

```
fetch.ContinueRequest(new Fetch.ContinueRequestCommandSettings()
{
   RequestId = e.RequestId
});
```

Below is your code updated to use `Fetch` which allowed the query to run for 2+ minutes and 5+ minutes before I manually stopped it:

(Note: ensure all of your DevTools as using the same version (i.e. 89 in my case) or you will get errors):

```
using V89 = OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V89;
using V89Net = OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V89.Network;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V89.Log;

var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.LogPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "chromedriver.log";
service.EnableVerboseLogging = true;
var options = new ChromeOptions();

new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig(), VersionResolveStrategy.MatchingBrowser);

var driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);

IDevTools devTools = driver as IDevTools;

var devToolsSession = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();

var fetch = devToolsSession.GetVersionSpecificDomains<V89.DevToolsSessionDomains>()
    .Fetch;
    
var enableCommandSettings = new V89.Fetch.EnableCommandSettings();

var requestPattern = new V89.Fetch.RequestPattern();
requestPattern.RequestStage = V89.Fetch.RequestStage.Response;
requestPattern.ResourceType = V89Net.ResourceType.Document;

enableCommandSettings.Patterns = new V89.Fetch.RequestPattern[] { requestPattern };

fetch.Enable(enableCommandSettings);

void RequestIntercepted(object sender, V89.Fetch.RequestPausedEventArgs e)
{

    e.Request.Url.Dump();

    fetch.ContinueRequest(new V89.Fetch.ContinueRequestCommandSettings()
    {
        RequestId = e.RequestId
    });
}

fetch.RequestPaused += RequestIntercepted;

while (true)
{
    driver.Url = "https://translate.google.com/";
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    driver.Navigate().Refresh();
}
```

Screenshot (From left-to-right): LinqPad output Console.Write.Url equivalent, Above code in LINQPad, and view of Chrome log file)

[image]

Comment: In My instance I needed to receive the Websocket connection and frames.
I ended up using ```Session.GetVersionSpecificDomains<OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V119.DevToolsSessionDomains>().Network```
which contained the API's for ```WebSocketCreated``` and ```WebSocketFrameReceived```.