# Handling network errors after a test in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome-devtools

##### The issue

I have seached a lot for a solution in C#, but none of them are working for me.
I can't use them because there are objects missing that I can't import or the objects are deprecated. (DesiredCapabilities for example)

##### What I want to do

All I want to do is after executing a test, to check in the tear down if something went wrong during the test.
When something went wrong the test should fail with message. (Assert.Fail)
The problem here is that I can't get the logs I want to see.

I will show what I have tried.

##### Version 1:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.SetLoggingPreference("performance", LogLevel.All);
```

```
var logs = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog("performance");
```

This works for me, but the issue here is that I can't see what's really wrong.
The message output just shows me that some error has happend, but not what error.

This is accepted solution like you can see here:

[How to set up performance logging in SeleniumWebdriver with Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56333865/13163366)

[Unable to get Chrome Performance logs in Selenium C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60553029/13163366)

##### Version 2:

The same like in version 1 with a little change

```
var logs = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);
```

The issue here is that I only get one log, but I want to get all logs from the execution.

##### Version 3:

This seems to me the most up to date solution, but again I have issues with accessing the objects.

[C# Selenium 4: Setup request interception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67335693/13163366)

##### Version 4:

I haven't tied this because that's not directly selenium, but maybe this could help.

[How do I see the raw HTTP request that the HttpWebRequest class sends?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25683524/13163366)

Update: It doesn't work like this.

##### Edit - Version 5:

There also some [official examples](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/support_packages/chrome_devtools/) with Chrome DevTools but not many of them are in C#

Something like [this](https://dotjord.wordpress.com/2020/09/13/how-to-capture-network-activity-with-selenium-4-in-asp-net-core-3-1/) should work, but I need to use this in my test not in a console application.

This is my current state:

```
IDevTools devTools = driver as IDevTools;
DevToolsSession session = devTools.CreateDevToolsSession();
session.Network.ResponseReceived += ResponseReceivedHandler;
session.Network.Enable(new EnableCommandSettings());

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
```

With this method:

```
public static void ResponseReceivedHandler(object sender, ResponseReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   Debug.WriteLine($"Url: { e.Response.Url } Status: { e.Response.Status } Type: { e.Response.MimeType } ");
}
```

##### Update 2:

I can get most of the time a e.Response.StatusText message and allways an status code, what I want to see is the msg object in the network tab.
(You can see it when you click on an item and then open the preview tab)

---

I hope you can help me out, it should work for chrome other browsers would be good but speciaclly for chrome it would help.

Comment: So you want to get the performance logs from Chrome and you are not able to?

Comment: If I can read network errors from them, then yes.
With the version I shared I don't get something like a response code or error message.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include more details about what information you need from the logs?

Comment: I have edited it, I will take a look again tomorrow. Thank you for trying to help :)

Comment: I solved it for myself some month ago, can tell now what the real problem was, but here you can find a working example how to do it in Selenium 4.0 :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/71671844/495455 Also the official examples are now updated:
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/support_packages/chrome_devtools/

Comment: There is nothing wrong with answering your own question. I've done that several times myself. Future readers might benefit if you posted an answer to this question.

Comment: I created this as a answer but it got converted as a comment from someone.

Comment: A good answer will do more than link to other web sites. An answer should show code, and explain how the code solves the problem in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclamer: Long answer for Selenium 4+ scroll down :)**

I solved it for myself some month ago, can tell now what the real problem was, but here you can find a working example how to do it in Selenium 4.0 :)

Here is some working code for alpha and beta, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71671844/13163366).

**Before chrome version specifications: (Until 4.0.0 alpha 5)**

```
IDevTools devTools = driver as IDevTools;
DevToolsSession session = devTools.CreateDevToolsSession();
session.Network.ResponseReceived += ResponseReceivedHandler;
session.Network.Enable(new EnableCommandSettings());
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

public void ResponseReceivedHandler(object sender, ResponseReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Status: { e.Response.Status } : {e.Response.StatusText} | File: { e.Response.MimeType } | Url: { e.Response.Url }");
}
```

**After chrome version specifications: (> 4.0.0 alpha 5)**

```
using DevToolsSessionDomains = OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V96.DevToolsSessionDomains;
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
var devTools = (IDevTools)driver;
IDevToolsSession session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
var domains = session.GetVersionSpecificDomains<DevToolsSessionDomains>();
domains.Network.ResponseReceived += ResponseReceivedHandler;
await domains.Network.Enable(new OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V96.Network.EnableCommandSettings());
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

void ResponseReceivedHandler(object sender, ResponseReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Status: { e.Response.Status } : {e.Response.StatusText} | File: { e.Response.MimeType } | Url: { e.Response.Url }");
}
```

**For Selenium 4+ versions**

I can recommend you to use a version  and browser unspecific approach: (Works in Chrome and Edge with Selenium 4.8)

```
public void SetupNetworkLogging(IWebDriver driver)
{
    NetworkManager manager = new NetworkManager(driver);
    manager.NetworkResponseReceived += ResponseHandler;

    Task monitoring = manager.StartMonitoring();
    monitoring.Wait();
}

private void ResponseHandler(object sender, NetworkResponseReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Http status: {e.ResponseStatusCode} : {e.ResponseBody} | Url: {e.ResponseUrl} ");
}
```

You can also experiment with a devtools session:

```
IDevTools devTools = driver as IDevTools;
var session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
var network = session.Domains.Network;

Task enableNetwork = network.EnableNetwork();
Task networkCaching = network.EnableNetworkCaching();
enableNetwork.Wait();
networkCaching.Wait();
```

I hope this was helpful for you - The official documentation can be found [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/). :)

Comment: domains.Network not working..